# Spring Scope proxy mode AspectJ?

Tags: java, spring, scope, aop

I want to implement some functionality to obtain the current logged in User (the JPA entity that represent the person that is current logged in). But instead of doing it in the classic way

```
CurrentUserService.getCurrentUser(){load the user from db by login})
```

I want to do it in a more CDI way.

I want to have a `CurrentUserFactory`, that provides the current user as an request scoped bean available with an custom qualifier (current bean).

Qualifier:

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface CurrentUser {
}
```

Factory:

```
@Component
public class CurrentUserFactory {

  @CurrentUser
  @Bean
  @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST,
         proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  public User currentUser() throws IllegalStateException {
      return
          <DoWhatIMean>
             User load form DB by:
             SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()
          </dwim>
}
```

Usage:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(…)
public AccountController() {

  @Resource
  @CurrentUser
  private User currentUser;

  @RequestMapping(params=”my”)
  public String myAccount () {
     return “redirect:/account/”+currentUser.id;
  }
 }
```

That works fine.

But it fails (with not realy usefull exceptions) if I use the current user for direct JPA (Hibernate) stuff like searching for an entity by reference to currentUser or storing an entity with reference to currentUser. -- (*This this fails is clear.*)

**The reason is that spring inject an CGI proxy in the currentUser. This works fine as long as one uses only properties of this proxy, but fails if one starts to use the reference itself.**

I know I am working at the edge of the specification and I accept if my idea does not work. But I want to ask you I have an idea to get it working. So that the developer can use this currentUser object like a normal JPA loaded Entity.

What I want at least is this very easy usage of current user only:

```
@Resouce
@CurrenctUser
User currentUser;
```

and that is it.

May someone has an idea to get it working, for example an AspectJ trick (I am using compile time AspectJ)?

---

Anyway: as I told before, the Exceptions are not my problem, I understand them because they are only indicators of the described problem.

Exception when I try to load by currentUser (`Select b From Bookmark b Where user=?`)

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException`: `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException`: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: `domain.User`

Exception when I try to save a bookmark (Bookmark has a field user)

> could not insert: [`domain.Bookmark`]; SQL [`insert into bookmark (businessId, reference_Folder_fk, title, user_fk) values (?, ?, ?, ?)`]; constraint [`null`]; nested exception is `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`: could not insert: [`domain.Bookmark`]

Comment: it would help to know what the exceptions are.

Comment: @matt b: I have added the exceptions.

Comment: is the User object being modified anywhere between fetching it and the `select b from bookmark b where user = ?` query?

Comment: @matt b: No it is not. But the problem is, that `@Ressource @CurrentUser User currentUser` is an Spring-Proxy, because its factory method is of Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST).

Answer (score 1):

The Spring proxy is created by ScopedProxyFactoryBean.  Its documentation says the proxy implements 'ScopedObject', which lets you access the original bean.

```
@Resource
@CurrentUser
private User currentUser;

public static <T> T unwrapScopedProxy(T maybeProxy) {
    if (maybeProxy instanceof ScopedObject) {
        return (T) ((ScopedObject) maybeProxy).getTargetObject();
    } else {
        return maybeProxy;
    }
}

...
query.setParameter("user", unwrapScopedProxy(currentUser));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to `ScopedProxyFactoryBean` and `ScopedObject` and for a hint how to unwrap. Anyway it does not solve the problem.  "What I want at least is this very easy usage of current user..." What you suggested is a client side solution (the programmer how use that style needs to take care of the correct handling at every point where he use that currentUser), what I need is a solution where the user how use the current user has to take no care. Only the programmer who PROVIDE the current user is allowed to do this extra infra structure stuff.

Comment: I see, so you're basically objecting that the client should have no knowledge of how the @Resource is implemented.  That is valid (and admirable that you're not compromising architectural purity for expediency).  What if you make a generic API?  `public interface ICurrentUserHolder { User getCurrentUser(); }`  One way or another you have to unwrap the proxy; you can hide the unwrapping behind an interface but it still has to be done.

Comment: You didn't say how you construct the Query, but another option would be to create a Spring Query wrapper that automatically unwraps any Spring proxies passed to `setParameter`.

Comment: Spring Query wrapper? - that sounds interesting. Is it a "officiel" concept of Spring? Can you give me some link where I can start with?

Comment: No, not official. I was imagining a custom proxy (returned by your Query factory, whatever it is).

Comment: Hey -- just thought of another option. Change your query to "where user.id = ?" and pass currentUser.getId().

Comment: thats all possible, but it influence the client side. So the standard way (`CurrentUserService` see my question) seams to be the only practical solution.